# Template Classes and Functions in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, abstract-data-type, template-classes

I have a question that confuses me. I know what is template and aim of it but I have some blank points on usage.

I have a Template class like that:

```
template <class elemType>
class SSorting {
public:

int seqSearch(const elemType list[], int length, const elemType& item);
};
```

When I code the member of a class function seqSearch I need to declare as:

```
template <class elemType>
int SSorting <elemType> :: seqSearch(const elemType list[], int length, const elemType& item){
    *statements*
}
```

Everything okay at this point. template  says this is a function that inside a template class and `int` in front of the function means that the function will return an integer value, but the part that I don't understand is why we have to write `SSorting <elemType> :: seqSearch` instead of `SSorting :: seqSearch`. I already say this is a member of a template class and return type why I we need to say `<elemType>` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should recall that class/function templates means that ***for each*** instantiation with a different template type, the compiler writes down another copy of the code, replacing `elemType` with the relevant type. Meaning, that if you are using in your code both `SSorting<double>` and `SSorting<int>`, you get two totally different types, with different names.

Thus, the name of the class **isn't** `SSorting`, but `SSorting<elemType>`!

Comment: If you think that this answer is correct (and answers your question), you should accept it, or at least upvote it

Comment: same nitpick here: correct term is "class template" not "template class" (and "function templates" not "template functions")

Comment: @idclev463035818 fixed

Comment: fixed the fix ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Excuse me for my bad grammar XD

Answer (score 0):

Template class is not a "real" class, it is template code. It does not exist until you use it. When you do not write "elemType" part in the definition part, you're just defining a member function of "real" class.

Comment: there are no template classes you mean "class template"

Comment: @walnut Yeah i know, i think im just generally confused by what they mean here :D